# Confusion on Exercise 3.6.ii in Riehl: showing the product is associative via a unique nat. isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, universal-property

This is an exercise (I believe) to practice methods using the functoriality of limits. The exercise is as follows:

> For any pair of objects $X,Y,Z$ in a category $\mathsf{C}$ with binary products, there is a unique natural isomorphism $(X \times Y) \times Z \cong X \times (Y \times Z)$ which commutes with the projections.

I should be able to do this "inside $C$" by using the universal property of the product, but I want to use the machinery we've developed in the chapter (functoriality of limits). So to show this is true, let $F,G : \bullet\bullet \to \mathsf{C}$ be the functors with images matching the factors above.

---

EDIT: for full clarity, the definition of $F,G : \bullet\bullet \to \mathsf{C}$ are: $$\begin{cases} F0 = (X \times Y) \\ F1 = Z \end{cases} \hphantom{1234} \begin{cases} G0 = X \\ G1 = (Y \times Z) \end{cases}$$

---

By picking their limits as the products above, a natural isomorphism $F \cong G$ induces a naturally-defined isomorphism $(X \times Y) \times Z \cong X \times (Y \times Z)$.

This is where I have some confusion. A natural transformation $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$ would consist of two morphisms $\alpha_0 : X \times Y \to X$ and $\alpha_1 : Z \to Y \times Z$. We can easily take $\alpha_0 := \pi_X$, but I am at a loss as to what $\alpha_1$ should be. A morphism into $Y \times Z$ is totally determined by its projections, but are we guaranteed that there is even a morphism $Z \to Y$?

If there is no such morphism, there certainly isn't a morphism $Z \to Y \times Z$, which makes constructing a natural transformation $F \Rightarrow G$ impossible. The fact that there certainly is a natural isomorphism $(X \times Y) \times Z \to X \times (Y \times Z)$ implies that my fear is not true, but I have no idea how to show it.

If I have made some error in my reasoning, please point it out, but for now I am simply looking for clarification on how to construct $\alpha$, and where my concerns break down.

Answer (score 3):

A morphism *into* a product breaks up into a pair of morphisms into the factors, but a morphism *from* a product doesn't necessarily break up like that. So you are not looking for morphisms $\alpha_0: X \times Y \to X$ and $\alpha_1: Z \to Y \times Z$. You can only break up the target. So you are looking for morphisms $\alpha_0: (X \times Y) \times Z \to X$ and $\alpha_1: (X \times Y) \times Z \to Y \times Z$. Now can you see what the morphisms are?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to say here. If I am trying to find a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$, it is pair of morphisms $F0 \to G0$ and $F1 \to G1$ (where 0 and 1 are objects of the discrete category $\bullet\bullet$); i.e., a pair of morphisms $X \times Y \to X$ and $Z \to Y \times Z$. I agree that a morphism into a product is determined by its factors--- my concern is that I can never find a morphism into the factor $Y$ from $Z$.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that your answer is a means to construct an isomorphism $(X \times Y) \times Z \to X \times (Y \times Z)$ via the universal property of the product? I know that I can do this directly, but I am trying to do this via functoriality of the limit.

Comment: Exactly what are the functors $F$ and $G$?

Comment: I've edited the post above with the explicit definition. Also, I made an error with some notation that I've fixed. I hope that the mistakes did not cause any confusion.

Comment: Ok, I understand now; the previous notation confused me. I don't think this approach will work because in general, there may be no morphism $Z \to Y$ and there certainly isn't any kind of "natural" one. If this problem is intended to be solved with functoriality of limits, perhaps the category on the left side of the functor should be 3 points rather than 2. I haven't thought it through.